# Fetching data from multiple sojbects - best practice

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

When it comes to fetching the data from different objects what is the best practice to follow in LWC? I have 6 different objects which I will be fetching the data from and it has been said to use `uiObjectInfoApi` adapter and it's super easy for sure but what will be the performance impact?, each custom objects has 500 fields.

Anything that I would watch out for? or I can pull specific fields instead of entire sobjects meta?

code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import {getObjectInfo, getObjectInfos} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi'
import OBJECT1 from '@salesforce/schema/sobject1__c'
import OBJECT2 from '@salesforce/schema/sobject2__c'
.......
export default class GetObjectInfoDemo extends LightningElement {  

    objectApiNames = [OBJECT1, OBJECT2, OBJECT3, OBJECT4, OBJECT5 ...]

    objectInfos
    @wire(getObjectInfos, { objectApiNames: '$objectApiNames' })
    objectInfosHandler({data}){
        if(data){
            console.log(data)
            this.objectInfos = data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your overall objective? Why are you fetching this data and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: overall objective is to get the data from different objects and show and the data would be readonly, meaning the user will not update the data, just display purpose.

Comment: _What data_? Records? Object schema?

Comment: just records, not the object schema

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong wire adapter for the purpose - fetching record data - you described in comments. The `uiObjectInfoApi` module is for [fetching sObject *metadata*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_object_info).

You most likely will want to build an [Apex method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex) that you'll call or wire to obtain your data. If you want to use an out-of-the-box wire adapter, you should be looking in the [`uiRecordApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record), although those adapters focus on single-record use cases.

You should review the section [Work with Salesforce Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data) from the LWC Developer Guide to understand the various ways to access record data from the LWC framework.

Comment: yep, I was not 100% sure if I'm using the right adapter so if I use out of the box wire adapter which is `uiRecordApi` and in this example it says connecting to one Object and retriving the records https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value if I use multiple wire for multipel objects is that something optimized or good approach ?

Comment: It is situation- and volume-dependent, but as I note above I think you most likely will want to build an Apex method to perform a retrieve, since you specified _records_ plural of _objects_ plural.